# Adding registry value at the beginning of installation with Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

how can I add a new user environment variable before inno-setup installation begins? the new variable is needed just during the installation process not after!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Comment: Tell us more about what you need the variable for.

Comment: tried to add/expand a registry value using following code and it works - but not at the beginning of installation rather at the end  :(    <br/>                                      [Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"; \
    ValueType: expandsz; ValueName: "Path"; ValueData: "{olddata};C:\foo"  <br/>       path value should exanded before installation begins - BeforeInstall flag does not work for [Registry] ?

Comment: @Martin one of the wizard page makes a db connection test to postgres which needs psql.exe on windows path.

Comment: How *exactly* does it test the connection?

Comment: @OP, it's because the `[Registry]` section is processed after installation. As for a Y part of your possible X/Y problem, how do you test the connection? Are you sure you need environment changes at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to write to the registry before the installation starts you can use the `CurStepChanged` event function. It would be something like this:

```
procedure CurStepChanged(CurrentStep: TSetupStep);
begin
    if CurrentStep = ssInstall then
    begin
        RegWriteStringValue(...)
    end;
end;
```

There are different RegWrite functions you could use: RegWriteStringValue, RegWriteExpandStringValue, RegWriteMultiStringValue, and others.

Comment: I'm aware that you are answering the literal question. But this is XY problem. OP needs to set the variables just for some suprocess of the installer. Modifing global registry for that is a bad idea.

Comment: ok guys.. i have found a solution to my specific problem without changing environement variable. @Bauer thx for the solution regarding changing registry before the installation starts. but RegWriteStringValue did not work for [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\Path] which has a type of REG_EXPAND_SZ..

Comment: What I tried to do was to add a new entry in windows path in registry and make a refreshEnvironement so that dependency in my case psql.exe works in batch file but as @Martin mentioned it was not a good idea.

Comment: @Martin: The changes can be removed from the registry also in `CurStepChanged` at `CurrentStep = ssPostInstall` or `CurrentStep = ssDone`. I would also recommend to write a user setting instead of a global setting if that fits for the task.